# Pararelle processing for Spectrum image

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Hi I'm using hyperspy for EELS data process.
I tried 2 models of gaussian for fitting spectrums(1D) in spectrum image(SI, 2D) but it didn't fit well.
So I write pixel-by-pixel fitting code using double 'for' sentence.
However, It takes very long time. For example, it takes about 30min for processing 240000 pixels.

I searched about multiprocessing python library for pararelle processing but it seem to be hard for use.

```
SizeX = highlosscrop_2.axes_manager[0].size
SizeY = highlosscrop_2.axes_manager[1].size

highlosscrop_2_array = np.array(highlosscrop_2)

Ni2peak = np.zeros((SizeY, SizeX))
Ni4peak = np.zeros((SizeY, SizeX))

start = time.time()

 NiEQspectrum = highlosscrop_2_array[j, i, :]

        NiEQspectrums = hs.signals.Signal1D(NiEQspectrum)

        NiEQspectrums.axes_manager[0].scale = highlosscrop_2.axes_manager[2].scale
        NiEQspectrums.axes_manager[0].units = highlosscrop_2.axes_manager[2].units
        NiEQspectrums.axes_manager[0].name = highlosscrop_2.axes_manager[2].name
        NiEQspectrums.axes_manager[0].offset = highlosscrop_2.axes_manager[2].offset


        m1=NiEQspectrums.create_model()

        g1 = hs.model.components1D.Gaussian() 
        g2 = hs.model.components1D.Gaussian() 

        # g1 fitting value

        # g2 fitting value

        m1.append(g1)
        m1.append(g2)


        m1.fit_component(g1, signal_range=(850., 856.), only_current=False)
        m1.fit_component(g2, signal_range=(854., 860.), only_current=False)


        m1.set_signal_range(845., 865.)
        m1.multifit()


        m1.reset_signal_range()
        # m1.plot(plot_components=True)

        #g1.print_current_values(fancy=True)
        #g2.print_current_values(fancy=True)
        
        Ni2peak[j,i] = g1.A.value
        Ni4peak[j,i] = g2.A.value
        
        
        del g1
        del g2
```

I want to keep pixel addresses for processed results(e.g. Ni2peak, Ni4peak).

I tried to write multiprocessing code but I failed.
The data should contain metadata(scale, offset, unit, name. etc)

Comment: What is `trange`? Isn't your problem that you have two-dimensional `numpy` arrays and you want to assign values to each element of those arrays using multiprocessing? If so, do we need to care about what those values are or how they are computed? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, tag your question with the platform you are on (Linux? Windows?).

Comment: trange shows progress bar while running 'for' loop

Comment: Oh, it's `tqdm`. I should have realized that, but it helps us when you post a minimal, reproducible example. i.e. code that is complete and can be run without change or additions and reproduces your error. By definition such code would contain all required import statements.

Comment: I updated. X-Y axis(pixel) should be in parallel process, and Z axis(spectrum) should exist their own shape and Z axis contains each value. I want to fit Z axis spectrum with those model functions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to apply the models G1 and G2 independently to each pixel individually. To do this in parallel you can use `Pool.map` from the `multiprocessing` module.

Here is a possible solution in pseudo-code, assuming your hyper-cube has the dimensions (SizeX, SizeY, Number_bands):

```
pix_count = SizeX * SizeY
spectra = hyper_cube.reshape((pix_count, Number_bands))  # make a list of all spectra

def calculate_model(spectrum):
    g1 = apply_gaussian(spectrum)
    g2 = apply_gaussian(spectrum)
    return (g1, g2)

if __name__ = "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)  # use 4 workers
    results = pool.map(calculate_model, args=(spectra,))
    ni2peak = [x[0] for x in results]
    ni4peak = [x[1] for x in results]

    ni2peak_arr = numpy.array(ni2peak)
    ni4peak_arr = numpy.array(ni4peak)

    ni2peak_arr = ni2peak_arr.reshape((SizeX, SizeY))
    ni4peak_arr = ni4peak_arr.reshape((SizeX, SizeY))
```